# Connection to PostgreSQL with python3 over SSH

Tags: python, postgresql

Try to connect PostgreSQL over ssh, but something went wrong. Could anybody help?

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import psycopg2

with SSHTunnelForwarder(
   "hostname",
   ssh_username="username",
   ssh_password="password",
   remote_bind_address=("127.0.0.1", 5432)) as server:

   try:
       conn = psycopg2.connect(host = "127.0.0.1", dbname="db_name",   user="db_user", password="db_password")
       cursor = conn.cursor()
       cursor.execute("""SELECT * from table""")
       rows = cursor.fetchall()
       print(rows)
   except Exception as e:
       print("Uh oh, can't connect. Invalid dbname, user or password?")
       print(e)
```

When run the code - get an error:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi.
>     `""")
>   Uh oh, can't connect. Invalid dbname, user or password?
>   could not connect to server: Connection refused
>       Is the server running on host`127.0.0.1`and accepting
>       **TCP/IP** connections on port`5432`?

Check db name, user and password many times, but it's now working.
Manual connection to db via ssh works good, but I need to do it in python to analyst data.

Comment: Pretty sure you need to set `port=server.local_bind_port` in your `psycopg2` connection string. By default, `sshtunnel` uses a random local port. You could also set `local_bind_address` when creating the tunnel.